# Can't see logs of kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, flannel, kubeadm

After installing kubernetes cluster following this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) I decided to check logs of system pod *kube-scheduler* to ensure that all works fine:

```
 kubectl logs --namespace kube-system kube-scheduler-user223225-pc
```

but I got next error message:

```
Error from server: Get https://10.2.2.131:10250/containerLogs/kube-system/kube-scheduler-user-pc/kube-scheduler: dial tcp 10.2.2.131:10250: getsockopt: no route to host
```

I try to get logs from other pods and got the same error.

I run the cluster on Ubuntu 16.04 and chose flannel network installed using the next commands:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
kubectl create --namespace kube-system -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Maybe, I missed something, also I see people suggest to configure firewall but it didn't help me:

```
sudo systemctl stop kubelet
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo ifconfig cni0 down
sudo ifconfig flannel.1 down
sudo ifconfig docker0 down

sudo service docker start
sudo service kubelet start

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i cni0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o cni0 -j ACCEPT
```

Does someone know how to fix the issue with getting logs? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes process log will be logged in node syslog. you can look at /var/log/syslog file.

to validate the cluster configuration use `kubectl` command.

e.g.

kubectl get nodes
kubectl get pods -o wide

also you can install the dashboard UI to check the cluster.

Comment: I have tried through dashboard UI too but I got the same message. All other commands such as `kubectl get nodes` or `kubectl get pods` work fine.

Comment: did you check the master node /var/log/syslog file?

Comment: Yes, I checked and got nothing suspicious after running command `logs`.

Comment: Log messages look like this:

`Jun 23 18:47:40 user223225-pc kubelet[5185]: I0623 18:47:40.065041    5185 operation_generator.go:597] MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "kubernetes.io/secret/5da95967-57ec-11e7-a9de-002522f9706f-flannel-token-bq608" (spec.Name: "flannel-token-bq608") pod "5da95967-57ec-11e7-a9de-002522f9706f" (UID: "5da95967-57ec-11e7-a9de-002522f9706f").`

Comment: I think you have network issue with your cluster. this command works for me 'kubectl  logs -n kube-system kube-scheduler-cm-01' in my cluster. can you give some more details about your environment? Are you using vagarnt?

Comment: No, I don't use vagrant. What kind of information do you need about my environment?

Comment: can you post this command output 'kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide'? Is kube-scheduler matches the master node ip?

Comment: No, not match.


`kube-scheduler-user223225-pc            1/1       Running   3          2d        10.2.2.131    user223225-pc`


`enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet   inet addr:10.2.3.216`

Comment: You pointed me the right direction ) The problem was with `/etc/hosts` -- the old ip address was set against the machine name. I've changed it and reinstalled kubeadm, after that logs started working !!)

Comment: Change your answer based on our discussion and I accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From discussion between  @sfgroups and @Kirill Liubun:

- The root cause of the issue: old ip address was set in `/etc/hosts` and was used during Kubernetes cluster set-up.  As a result there was an IP address mismatch between `kube-scheduler` pod and master node IP.
- Issue has been resolved by fixing `/etc/hosts`, changing IP address to correct one and reinstalling kubernetes cluster using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)