# how to remove kubernetes with all it's dependencies Centos 7

Tags: kubernetes

i want to uninstall kubernetes from Centos 7 and all it's dependencies and files like :

```
kube-apiserver 
kube-controller-manager  
kubectl                  
kubelet                  
kube-proxy                
kube-scheduler
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698283/how-to-completely-uninstall-kubernetes) or else these steps should help,

First clean up the pods running into your k8s cluster using,

```
$ kubectl delete node --all
```

then remove data volumes and back-up(if it's not needed) from your host system. Finally, you can stop all the k8s services using the script,

```
$ for service in kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kubectl kubelet kube-proxy kube-scheduler; do
      systemctl stop $service
  done
$ yum -y remove kubernetes #if it's registered as a service
```