# kubectl message appearing every time when I start the terminal

Tags: terminal, kubernetes, minikube

I have uninstalled minikube through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253264/6039697) post and now every time I open the terminal this message appears:

```
kubectl: command not found

Command 'minikube' not found, did you mean:

  command 'minitube' from deb minitube

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

---

I have no idea what is going on. Can someone help me to stop this message from appearing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have entries in your `~/.bashrc` file that are both calling `minikube` or/and `kubectl`.  Just edit/remove those entries. For example:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

In the `vi` editor:

```
/kubectl
dd
/minikube
dd
:wq
```

Comment: You are right. This are the last two lines:
`source <(kubectl completion bash)`
`source <(minikube completion bash)`