# kubectl proxy not working on Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, kubectl, kubernetes-dashboard

I've installed Kubernetes on ubuntu 18.04 using [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu). Everything is working fine and then I tried to install Kubernetes dashboard with [these instructions](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

Now when I am trying to run `kubectl proxy` then the dashboard is not cumming up and it gives following error message in the browser when trying to access it using default kubernetes-dashboard URL.

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

Following commands give this output where kubernetes-dashboard shows status as CrashLoopBackOff

$> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default                amazing-app-rs-59jt9                         1/1     Running            5          23d
default                amazing-app-rs-k6fg5                         1/1     Running            5          23d
default                amazing-app-rs-qd767                         1/1     Running            5          23d
default                amazingapp-one-deployment-57dddd6fb7-xdxlp   1/1     Running            5          23d
default                nginx-86c57db685-vwfzf                       1/1     Running            4          22d
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-nqphx                     0/1     Running            14         25d
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-psdv4                     0/1     Running            14         25d
kube-system            etcd-master-node                             1/1     Running            8          25d
kube-system            kube-apiserver-master-node                   1/1     Running            42         25d
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-master-node          1/1     Running            11         25d
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-95lvl                  1/1     Running            8          25d
kube-system            kube-proxy-qcpqm                             1/1     Running            8          25d
kube-system            kube-scheduler-master-node                   1/1     Running            11         25d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b64584c5c-kvz5d   1/1     Running            0          41m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   12         41m
```

$> kubectl get services --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   ----------      <none>        443/TCP                  25d
default                nginx                       NodePort    ----------    <none>        80:32188/TCP             22d
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   ----------      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   25d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   ----------   <none>        8000/TCP                 24d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   ----------    <none>        443/TCP                  24d



$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   ======       <none>        443/TCP                  25d
default                nginx                       NodePort    ======    <none>        80:32188/TCP             22d
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   ======      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   25d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   ======   <none>        8000/TCP                 24d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   ======    <none>        443/TCP                  24d
```

$ kubectl get events -n kubernetes-dashboard

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON    OBJECT                                      MESSAGE
24m         Normal    Pulling   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk   Pulling image "kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0-rc2"
4m46s       Warning   BackOff   pod/kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk   Back-off restarting failed container
```

$ kubectl describe services kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard

```
Name:              kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:         kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:            k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard"...
Selector:          k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.241.62
Port:              <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

$ kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk -n kubernetes-dashboard

```
> 2020/01/29 16:00:34 Starting overwatch 2020/01/29 16:00:34 Using
> namespace: kubernetes-dashboard 2020/01/29 16:00:34 Using in-cluster
> config to connect to apiserver 2020/01/29 16:00:34 Using secret token
> for csrf signing 2020/01/29 16:00:34 Initializing csrf token from
> kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret panic: Get
> https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf:
> dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
> 
> goroutine 1 [running]:
> github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.(*csrfTokenManager).init(0xc0003dac80)
>         /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:40
> +0x3b4 github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.NewCsrfTokenManager(...)
>         /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:65
> github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).initCSRFKey(0xc000534200)
>         /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:494
> +0xc7 github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).init(0xc000534200)
>         /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:462
> +0x47 github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.NewClientManager(...)
>         /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:543
> main.main()
>         /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:105
> +0x212
```

Any suggestions to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: logs from the pod which is in crashloopbackoff?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu same with `kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk`
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk" not found

Comment: what does kubectl get events  -n kubernetes-dashboard  and kubectl describe services kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard say?

Comment: `kubectl get events` - No resources found in default namespace.

Comment: @CodeRunner add namespace to your `kubectl` command `kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-566f567dc7-w2sbk -n kubernetes-dashboard`

Comment: updated OP with details with output from commands mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the guide You used to install kubernetes cluster is missing one important part.

According to kubernetes documentation:

> For  `flannel`  to work correctly, you must pass  `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`  to  `kubeadm init`.
>
> Set  `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables`  to  `1`  by running  `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`  to pass bridged IPv4 traffic to iptables’ chains. This is a requirement for some CNI plugins to work, for more information please see  [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/network-plugins/#network-plugin-requirements).
>
> Make sure that your firewall rules allow UDP ports 8285 and 8472 traffic for all hosts participating in the overlay network. see  [here](https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/troubleshooting.html#firewalls) .
>
> Note that  `flannel`  works on  `amd64`,  `arm`,  `arm64`,  `ppc64le`  and  `s390x`  under Linux. Windows (`amd64`) is claimed as supported in v0.11.0 but the usage is undocumented.
>
> ```sh
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/2140ac876ef134e0ed5af15c65e414cf26827915/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
> ```
>
> For more information about  `flannel`, see  [the CoreOS flannel repository on GitHub](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) .

To fix this:

I suggest using the command:

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
```

And then reinstall flannel:

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

---

Update: After verifying the the `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` value is `1` by default `ubuntu-18-04-lts`. So issue here is You need to access the dashboard locally.

If You are connected to Your master node via ssh. It could be possible to use `-X` flag with ssh in order to launch we browser via `ForwardX11`. Fortunately `ubuntu-18-04-lts` has it turned on by default.

```
ssh -X server
```

Then install local web browser like chromium.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

```
chromium-browser
```

And finally access the dashboard locally from node.

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `kubectl delete -f kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml` throws error error: the path "kubectl" does not exist. is there any typo

Comment: Indeed. I have edited my answer. You can try to restart flannel pods instead but I'm not sure if that will be enough. You may also need to rejoin workers if they don't show up on node list. I will show how deal with that if that happens.

Comment: Updated answer again. Try `sudo kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml` .

Comment: tried both commands and rebooted machine as well, but same error.

Comment: Try to use `curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` on Your master node.

Comment: I've cleared everything with https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253264/8074328 and try it from scratch. any reliable article or blog post? I want to setup kube8, dashboard and then rancher.

Comment: I suggest following official kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/). As for the guide you linked. Everything worked correctly on GCP Compute Engine VM with `ubuntu-18-04-lts` image. As for accessing dashboard it has to be accessed locally from node with the guide You linked.

Comment: I edited the answer and added workaround for accessing dashboard on server side web browser using ssh `-X` flag.